# Erro na inicialização do AVD - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Quando o emulador do android é iniciado ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
07-22 15:14:14.669    2387-2488/com.android.systemui E/JavaBinder﹕ Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.Parcel.writeException(Parcel.java:1389)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:410)
     Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
            at android.content.IIntentReceiver$Stub$Proxy.performReceive(IIntentReceiver.java:124)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.scheduleRegisteredReceiver(ActivityThread.java:866)
            at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:395)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)**

07-22 15:14:23.703      690-948/? E/NetlinkEvent﹕ NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'TIME_NS' not found
07-22 15:14:23.732      690-948/? E/NetlinkEvent﹕ NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'TIME_NS' not found
07-22 15:14:28.823      690-948/? E/NetlinkEvent﹕ NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'TIME_NS' not found
07-22 15:14:28.837      690-948/? E/NetlinkEvent﹕ NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'TIME_NS' not found**
```

Comment: JcSaint, já tentou excluir a maquina virtual e criar novamenteo com um nome diferente?

Comment: Essa é a primeira máquina da instalação. Ao olhar o SDK Manager percebi que os packages ArmEABI v7 e Intel x86 Atom, estão quebrados (Broken) vou deletar e reinstala-los.

Answer (score 1):

O recomendado é você deixar todo o seu Android SDK atualizado com os últimos pacotes disponibilizados.

Aqui no blog do Felipecosse tem um link que explica perfeitamente as configurações iguais a dos celulares que tem na lista! Basta seguir e vai tudo dar certo!

http://felipecosse.com.br/2011/06/30/criacao-do-emulador-android-adv-com-configuracoes-iguais-ao-celular/

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 1):

Adicione no arquivo app >> manifest >> AndroidManifest.xml
dentro da div application a seguinte tag:

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

obs: Não se esqueça de retirá-la quando for publicar o App.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente verificar os itens do seu SDK.
Baixar atualizações, e, se nada funcionar, excluir o plugin da IDE e instalar novamente.
Além disso, eite dar mais de 768 de memória pra uma VM porque pode ocorrer de ela crashar mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Delete e recrie sua maquina virtual, se não funcionar tente atualizar seu SDK.
Se ainda assim não funcionar baixe outro SDK, o seu pode estar faltando arquivos.